# How to ignore message in Teams Bot while dialog is active?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using a `ComponentDialog` which walks the user through four `WaterfallDialog` steps.

In the initial method called in reaction to the user's input, the dialog has to perform an operation that will take a while to complete, then moves on to the next dialog:

```cs
async Task<DialogTurnResult> SearchQueryStep_1(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await LongRunningOperation();

    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(
    nameof(SearchQueryDialog),
    new SearchQueryDialog.DialogInput
    {
        UserInput = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text
    },          
    cancellationToken);
}
```

If the user sends another message while the dialog is already active and still busy executing `LongRunningOperation()` the resulting outputs will be out of order.

How can I ignore messages coming from the same user and let them know to be a bit patient?

Note: the bot is **only** for Teams. Any Teams-specific solution would therefore be fine.

Comment: I don't use Dialogs at all, so this is just a suggestion, but storing a value in user state that the dialog sequence is in progress (and then clearing it afterwards) might help. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp